# ZeroMQ, have developers dropped .Net binding support entirely?

Tags: ipc, messaging, zeromq

I am looking for updates to the .Net bindings of the ZeroMQ libraries but do not seem to be able to find any. ZeroMQ is in version 4.0.3 but the only .Net binding offered on its website is version 2.1. And Nuget only seems to have version 2.2.5, which are both far behind the current version. I find that a bit bizarre given that some of the absolutely most obscure languages are supported. Am I missing something here?

Also, I seem to have serious problems even finding out whether any of the .Net bindings offer UDP support for data streaming and also what is the deal with multi-casting?

Should .Net not be actively supported by the ZeroMQ guys anymore can you recommend alternative light-weight broker-less solutions that support .Net and perform similarly in terms of throughput and latency than ZMQ?

Thanks

Comment: To be fair, I dug up a 3.0 version (through usage of the 3.0.0.0 interop library) but still that is one full version behind the 4.0.3 which is claimed to be stable on the ZMQ website. Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current choice for ZeroMQ on .Net seems to be [netmq](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq), which is a .Net *port* of libzmq. I think that may be why the .Net bindings have not been kept up to date.

The Java community has taken a similar approach, favoring [jeromq](https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq) over the jzmq binding.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I feel a bit disappointed because I am using ZeroMQ since a very early version, and terminology and naming conventions seem to change **all the time** and the term backward compatibility is non-existent. Leaves very little confidence to ever consider this library for any larger projects.

Comment: There are very few backward-incompatible changes between 2.2 and 4.1. There are many *new* things, but old APIs are generally kept for backward compatibility.